# More precise priority for commands

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rich-text-editor, lexicaljs

I have a custom plugin with custom command that sends data and clears editor on Enter key. Something like that:

```
useEffect(() => {
    return mergeRegister(
        editor.registerCommand(KEY_ENTER_COMMAND, (event) => {
            //send data and clear editor logic
            return true;
        }, COMMAND_PRIORITY_LOW),
    );
}, [editor]);
```

It prevents RichTextPlugin from creating new line. But im also using MentionsPlugin, so if i type "@hello" it shows me the list of available mention options and when i press enter it selects mention and adds mention node. At the same time my custom plugin sends data and clears editor. The problem is that RichTextPlugin listens for enter key with priority EDITOR (0), and MentionsPlugin listens with priority LOW (1). So i can't set my priority between them. Right now the only solution i've found is to copy entire MentionsPlugin (337 lines of code) and change LOW to NORMAL. Is there any way to make it work easier?